# How can I set a label for the index column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset and I am using reset_index to reset the index:

```
output = output.reset_index(drop=True)
```

This works properly but I end up with an index column with no label. In other words all of the other columns have labels set, except the first column in the spreadsheet. I would like that index column to have the label "Index".

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `rename_axis`

```
output = output.rename_axis('Index')
```

Comment: This worked for me, thanks!

This is how I used it: output = output.reset_index(drop=True).rename_axis('Index')

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the name argument:

```
output = output.reset_index(name='Index')
```

---

```
output = output.reset_index(name='Index', drop=True)
```

Comment: Notable that only [`Series.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html) has a `name` argument. [`DataFrame.reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html) does not.

Comment: @HenryEcker Yeah!

Answer (score 0):

Index label is its attribute. You can change it via an assignment:

```
output.index.name = "Index"
```